# Mapping two tables to one entity in Doctrine2

Tags: orm, symfony1, doctrine-orm, data-modeling

I'm looking at using doctrine for an application I'm working on - but after reading the documentation I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to represent the database structure we have in terms of entities.

I have many tables which have partner tables which hold translation data like the following....

[image: Tables ER diagram]

Where I would like to have one Entity (Navigation Element) which had access to the 'label' field depending on what Language I set in my application. The following from the Doctrine documentation seems to suggest that you need to define one (single) table which is used to persist an entity

> http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html
>   By default, the entity will be
>   persisted to a table with the same
>   name as the class name. In order to
>   change that, you can use the @Table
>   annotation as follows:

Or do I need to define two entities and link them (or allow the translation table to inherit from the element table).

And what strategy would I use to always insert a language_id clause to the Join (to ensure I'm pulling the right label for the currently set language). Is this something I would define in the entity itself, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to suit a [One-To-Many Bidirectional association](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional). This is the scenario from that page translated to your situation:

```
/** @Entity */
class NavigationElement
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="NavigationElementTranslation", mappedBy="navigationElement")
     */
    private $translations;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->translations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class NavigationElementTranslation
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="NavigationElement", inversedBy="translations")
     * @JoinColumn(name="navigation_element_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $navigationElement;
    // ...
}
```

You could add a `getLabel($languageId)` method to the NavigationElement entity that searches through the translations to get the correct label:

```
public function getLabel($languageId) {

    foreach($this->translations as $trans) {
        if($trans->languageId == $languageId)
            return $trans->label;
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
}
```

And you could use the following DQL to ensure you only load the translation you want into the `$translations` property:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT ne, net
     FROM Entity\NavigationElement ne
     JOIN ne.translations net WITH net.languageId = :langId"
);
$query->setParameter('langId', $languageId);
$navigationElements = $query->execute();
```

This situation sounds like one where you would want to cache aggressively. Make sure you look into [Doctrine 2's caching](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/caching.html) mechanisms too.

Also, internationalization can be handled reasonably well in PHP with [gettext](https://www.php.net/gettext) if you find join tables for translations start to become unmanageable.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this really great explanation. I guess I had a problem understanding the need to create an entity (translation) which doesn't (in of itself) have meaning within my domain - but of course given the example you've provided I don't to access it directly, but rather transparently though the element itself.

Comment: rojoca's answer is quite good, but his last sentence is also a big hint.  Your intuition was correct: internationalization (I18N) is tricky, and it's often better to abstract that stuff away from your domain.  gettext can be very helpful, and there are other mechanisms.  Zend_Locale and Zend_Translate from ZF can be usefully used apart from the framework, for example.  If this is a big project, and you need to do a lot of translation, (and have time), I'd take a big step back and start doing some research on i18n.

Comment: @timdev Thanks for the comment. The scope of the project is only (at the moment) to model the way our system is functioning *now*. Thankfully it is not very sophisticated so my solution doesn't need to be either (I'm not trying to add functionality that is not already there) And you're right - My understanding of i18n is very limited, though in this specific case I only need to deal with simple translations of the names of (a few) domain objects. I'll take a look at the Packages you mention and also symfony's localization and internationalization features.

Answer (score 0):

I would also direct anyone who has to tackle this same problem to take a look at the following doctrine extension.

http://www.gediminasm.org/article/translatable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2

Comment: Just a note to anyone who stumbles on this: The above extension uses EAV for storing data and is therefore extremely inefficient for anything other than small datasets. If you have a large number of entities that need translated and you care about performance you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Can you really classify something as "extremely inefficient" just because using EAV? I'm not an expert, but maybe this takes care of some performance issues http://www.gediminasm.org/article/translatable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2#orm-query-hint

Comment: @calumbrodie That link is offline (404); checked on 2016-06-08